# How Restart My Bingo Board when I clicked Button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I searched 'How Restart my GUI if I pressed Button' or somethings and I changed my source, but it doesn't work. I want to chagne number to "X" when I clicked a Button.

```
Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));


    JB = new JButton[25];   

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
    {
        j = (int)(Math.random()*25);

        temp = nums[0];
        nums[0] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }


    for(int i=0; i<JB.length; i++)
    {
        JB[i] = new JButton(nums[i]);
        JB[i].addActionListener(this); 
        c.add(JB[i]);
    }

    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == JB[i])
        {
            System.out.println(nums[i]); 
            ***nums[i] = "X";  //I want show "X" when I clicked a Button***
            JB[i] = new JButton(nums[i]);
            restart();
        }
    }
}

public void restart()  // I deleted.
{

    start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
JB[i].setText(nums[i]);
```

instead of this:

```
JB[i] = new JButton(nums[i]);
```

to change button text. No restart needed (I think this is what you're trying to do?)

Comment: @user3489754 You're welcome :) you should mark the question as solved now. Welcome to SO!